# Numbers in a prepared statement changing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using a for loop to create n prepared statements, and incrementing a number in these statements. I am having a problem with the query where these numbers are being used. Last1 is the largest number used the last time this was run + 1, and last 2 is the largest number we will use this time. Here is the loop and query:

```
$last1 = 102;//these are normally pulled from the db, but I am specifying them here
$last2 = 104;//they are being pulled correctly, I already checked. I even tried it with specifying the variables, like this, same result.

for($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++){

    $q[$i] = "INSERT INTO outboundApps (fk_outboundAppKey, name, browser, fk_urls, fk_routes, virtualPlatform, autoAnswer, fk_GET, fk_callRates)
                       VALUES                   (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


    $stmt[$i] = mysqli_prepare($con, $q[$i]) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR);
    $stmt[$i]->bind_param("issiisiis", $last1, $arr[$i][$x]/*name*/, $arr[$i][$x=$x+1]/*type/browser*/, $last1, $last1, $arr[$i][$x=$x+2]/*virtual platform*/, $d = 1, $last1, $arr[$i][$x=$x+3]/*call rates*/);
    $x = $x+4;

    $last1++;
}
```

To add it to the database, I just do a for loop through the array $stmt[]. In theory, when this is executed, I should get something like the following added to the database:

```
102, Out 1, XML, 102, 102, default, 1, 102, rate1
103, Out 2, HTML, 103, 103, default, 1, 103, rate2
```

Instead, both rows look like this when they are added to the db:

```
104, Out 1, XML, 104, 104, default, 104, rate1
104, Out 2, HTML, 104, 104, default, 104, rate2
```

Any ideas why this is happening? When the statement is finally executed, is it using the final value of last1, instead of the value of last1 when the statement was prepared?

edit3: I dropped $n, the whole thing increments through $i, but that is still not the point of the question.

Comment: Where do you actually execute these queries?

Comment: You're only binding values to your statement, you must be executing it elsewhere in which case the last bound values are the ones you are inserting.

Comment: Also, note that you are assigning everything to the index $n, which never changes

Comment: I said I do a for loop that just loops through and executes mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt[$i]). And incrementing the index $i instead of $n was just a typo, which I fixed.

Comment: You are incrementing $n now?  That raises the upper limit of your for() loop, which makes this an infinite loop

Comment: Now the loop increments correctly, I wasnt thinking when I changed it to $n, and fixed it right away.

Comment: You are now incrementing $n inside the `for()` loop, which still results in an infinite loop because `$n` will always be greater or equal to `$i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind_param` binds parameters to the query when it is executed. Whenever `$stmt[$n]` is executed it will use the parameters at that time. After the loop has ran `$last1` is the last value and any executions will use this value.

A simpler way is just to loop and execute at the same time.

Comment: One more related sub-question. Do mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt[$i]) and mysqli_commit($con) need to be in the same function, or can I call one with execute, and the next with commit?

Comment: `mysqli_commit` only needs called if autocommit is set to false. If it is then calling `mysqli_commit` after all executions will write all the inserts to the db.